# What is the equivalent of Debian's "keyscript" in Fedora?

Tags: linux, debian, encryption, fedora, luks

I am trying to put together a specific setup in Fedora. On boot, I should be asked for a password to unlock a keyfile located on a USB drive.

Afterwards, the system proceeds to boot normally. The only partitions are `/` on the HDD and `/boot` on the USB. The keyfile is located on the USB.

On Debian it was a fairly simple matter of editing `/etc/crypttab` and writing:

```
sda_crypt UUID=**** /boot/keyfile.gpg luks,keyscript=/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_gnupg
```

then adding the keyfile to the LUKS keychain and updating initramfs. The same procedure does not seem to work on Fedora.

What is the equivalent of Debian's "keyscript" in Fedora and is it even possible to have such a setup on Fedora?